# Laravel 8: Extending UserCrudController from Package BackPack Permission-Manager

Tags: permissions, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I want to add Department field in User entity, so I decided to extend the default UserCrudController from this package https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager.

So I created a custom controller with this command `php artisan make:controller Admin\UserController`

In file \app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php I also add this (as instructed)

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController::class, 
            \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::class,
        );

    }
```

Then here is the content of \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

class UserController extends UserCrudController
{
    public function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        parent::setupCreateOperation();

        $fields['departments'] = [
            'label'     => 'Departments',
            'type'      => 'select2_multiple',
            'name'      => 'tags',
            'entity'    => 'tags',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model'     => "App\Models\Tag",
            'pivot'     => true,
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-6 col-md-4'],
            'options'   => (function ($query) {
                return $query->where('type', 'Department')->get();
            }),
        ];

        foreach($fields as $key=>$field) {
            CRUD::addField($field);
        }
        
    }

    public function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        parent::setupUpdateOperation();
        $this->setupCreateOperation();

        
    }
}
```

All seems fine, I can see all default information such as: username, email, roles, permission and my custom department fields.

The problem is, when I try to **modify an existing user** adding some Departments, I got this error

```
The email has already been taken.
The password field is required.
```

Somehow it's treated as new user registration. What could be the problems?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I solved it by copying `setupCreateOperation` to setupUpdateOperation.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

class UserController extends UserCrudController
{

    ...     

    public function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        parent::setupUpdateOperation();

        $fields['departments'] = [
            'label'     => 'Departments',
            'type'      => 'select2_multiple',
            'name'      => 'tags',
            'entity'    => 'tags',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model'     => "App\Models\Tag",
            'pivot'     => true,
            'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-6 col-md-4'],
            'options'   => (function ($query) {
                return $query->where('type', 'Department')->get();
            }),
        ];

        foreach($fields as $key=>$field) {
            CRUD::addField($field);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully there's a shorter way to reduce this duplication.